# How can I make an input grow from right to left on focus?

Tags: css, input, width, transition

The input is on the right side of the screen. How can I do this with only CSS (no JS)?

HTML:

CSS:

```
input[type="text"] {
    background: #444;
    border: 0 none;
    color: #d7d7d7;
    width:50px;
    padding: 6px 15px 6px 35px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin:3px 12px;
    transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
    background:#ccc;
    color: #6a6f75;
    width: 1200px;    
    margin:3px 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `display:flex` and `justify-content: end;` to your parent container

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


body{
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  margin:0;
  background-color: bisque;
}

.container{
  background-color: aquamarine;
  width: 1200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
}


input[type="text"] {
  background: #444;
  border: 0 none;
  color: #d7d7d7;
  width:50px;
  padding: 6px 15px 6px 35px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin:3px 12px;
  transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
  
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  background:#ccc;
  color: #6a6f75;
  width: 1200px;    
  margin:3px 12px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
      <input type="text" placeholder="search" />
    </div>
```